# What gives nerves their silver colour?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, histology

I always thought the silver colour specific to nerves was due to the myelin sheaths, but I've observed that unmyelinated C fibres display that same silvery appearance. Where does this colour come from? And can you distinguish myelinated from unmyelinated fibre bundles with the naked eye from their colour?

Comment: I don't know if I've heard "silver" as a color description for nerves of any type..white maybe in the context of white matter? Where are you seeing C fibers?

Comment: So I'm taking this from experiments done in animals. The spinal cord basically looks like a big, thick, silver straw (I always looked at the dorsal half, so including the dorsal columns which are Abeta fibres). I recently had a look at nerve around the splenic artery (which consists of C fibres almost exclusively). All these nerve to me look like silver shiny straws. I would love to attach some photos but I'm not sure that's appropriate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**
I think the whitish color is due to the outer layer of nerve bundles: the **[epineurium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epineurium)**. This surrounds all nerves, whether they contain myelinated fibers, unmyelinated fibers, or both.

**Background**
Nerves are bundles of axons (Fig. 1). Whether the axons are myelinated or not, the gross anatomy is similar; axons within a nerve are bundled into fascicles and surrounded by perineurium. Those fascicles are again bundled up and surrounded by **[epineurium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epineurium)**. It is this epineurium that you probably are seeing and it has a whitish appearance (Fig. 2).

The surface of a nerve therefore does not contain myelin; myelin is present around individual axons and is not exposed. Hence, whether a nerve contains myelinated axons, unmyelinated ones, or both will not determine its outward appearance.

[image: nerve]
<sup>Fig. 1. Anatomy of a nerve bundle. source: [EasyNoteCards](http://www.easynotecards.com/print_cards/60951)</sup>

[image: epineurium]
<sup>Macroscopic view of a nerve targeted for epineurial repair. source: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epineurial_repair)</sup>

Comment: Ah that makes sense to me, thanks a lot for this detailed answer @AliceD !